# How does SQL Server determine the style for convert when it isn't specified?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

**Update: This is a bug but [won't get fixed until the next release of SQL Server due to backward compatibility concerns.](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/595374/converting-date-and-time-values-to-varchar-gives-seemingly-unpredictable-results)**

This is following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634647/problem-with-the-use-of-top-1-in-a-query/3634752#3634752) which I answered but am still puzzled by.

Adding `TOP (1)` to a query is sufficient to change the result from "Sep  3 2010" to  "2010-09-03" (at least on my machine with British settings) can anyone explain why? Is this a bug or is it documented somewhere?

NB: I also found in the below that if I used a `#temp` table then both queries returned `2010-09-03`

```
USE tempdb

BEGIN TRAN

CREATE TABLE t (d DATETIME NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO t VALUES (GETDATE())

SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '')
FROM t
/*
Returns "Sep  3 2010"

[Expr1004] = Scalar Operator(CONVERT(varchar(50),
                                     CONVERT(date,[tempdb].[dbo].[t].[d],0),
                                     0)+
                             CONVERT(varchar(50),[@1],0))
*/

SELECT TOP 1 (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '')
FROM t
/*
[Expr1004] = Scalar Operator(CONVERT(varchar(50),
                                     CONVERT(date,[tempdb].[dbo].[t].[d],0),
                                     121)+
                             '')
Returns "2010-09-03"
*/

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: FYI, I can't repro on x64 SQL Server 2005 SP1 with us_english

Comment: @gbn, How'd you even get it to run in 2005 when the `DATE` datatype is new in 2008?

Comment: On 2005 I don't get this either (substituting `SMALLDATETIME` or `DATETIME` in place of `DATE`)

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: as per Martin Smith.. changed datatype

Comment: Seems like it has something to do with the `DATE` datatype itself then?

Comment: @Joe - Yes it seems that way actually. When I try the datatype substitution to `datetime` or `smalldatetime` on my SQL 2008 instance where I was originally testing I don't see the issue either. It uses `CONVERT(... ,0)` for both. Not `CONVERT(... ,121)`

Comment: some light reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @DForck42 - I read that earlier but couldn't see an explanation in there. Did you then?

Comment: @martin, no i didn't.  i just posted it for a reference on default formats for conversion

Comment: Martin, It is a bug contact SQL Server Customer Service and Support (CSS) and report it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that auto-parameterization is to blame for the inconsistency.

Books Online [documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) that DATE, TIME, DATETIME2, and DATETIMEOFFSET use CONVERT style 121 by default, whereas style 0 is used for DATETIME and SMALLDATETIME. Someone forgot to update the auto-parameterization rules for the new types :)

Where the query can be auto-parameterized, style 0 is erroneously applied to the new DATE/TIME types if an implicit conversion, or an explicit conversion without a specified style takes place. The query without TOP is auto-parameterized (parameter [@1] appears instead of the TIME literal). TOP is one of the (many) query features that prevents auto-parameterization.

The obvious workaround is to always specify a desired style when using CONVERT.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a good explanation for the observed behaviour!

Answer (score 1):

weird.  i copied yoru code, removed the comments, and removed the addition to the date, and it comes out fine on both of them.

```
    BEGIN TRAN 

CREATE TABLE t (d DATETIME NOT NULL) 
INSERT INTO t VALUES (GETDATE()) 

SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d)))
FROM t 


SELECT TOP 1 (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d)))
FROM t 

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Yes. The ` + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '')` was needed to get the behaviour (it was based on the code [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634647/problem-with-the-use-of-top-1-in-a-query/3634752#3634752) Does that mean you managed to reproduce the issue I see with the original code? If so are you on British language/datetime settings or can I rule that out as being relevant?

Comment: @martin, i'm running u.s.  i'd chalk it up to a waky error in sql server

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce, SQL 2008 R2 x64.

`TOP (n)`, `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, and windowing functions all produce the YYYY-MM-DD date. `ORDER BY` does not.

Thus, I'd guess it has something to do w/ spools in tempdb, internal vs localized representations, and the automatic switching back and forth that ought to be occurring, but somehow isn't in this case.

```
--------------------------------  
-- these return Sep  4 2010
--------------------------------  
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '') FROM t
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '') FROM t ORDER BY 1 ASC
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '') FROM t ORDER BY 1 DESC

--------------------------------  
-- these return 2010-09-04
--------------------------------  
-- GROUP BY
SELECT c FROM (SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '') FROM t) t (c) GROUP BY c
-- DISTINCT 
SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '') FROM t
-- TOP (n)
SELECT TOP (5) (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '') FROM t
-- COUNT(*) OVER ()
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (), (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '') FROM t
-- ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '') FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug; I can reproduce on 2008 x64 developer.

I did discover something quite strange; adding another date (or datetime) to varchar cast to the query causes the formats to be normalised. So:

```
USE tempdb

BEGIN TRAN

declare @d date = getdate()

CREATE TABLE t (d DATETIME NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO t VALUES (GETDATE())

SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '')
,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@d))
FROM t


SELECT TOP 1 (CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),CONVERT(DATE, d))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), '')
,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),@d))
FROM t

ROLLBACK
```

(note the addition of the converted variable @d to both queries)
Produces:

```
2010-09-06  2010-09-06
2010-09-06  2010-09-06
```

as output.

Format 121 appears to be the default covert format for `DATE` whereas 0 is the default covert format for `DATETIME`. I wondered whether the problem is caused by the first query ignoring the innermost `CONVERT`, or applying it out of order?