# LEFT Function in SQL Server returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I am trying to place data corresponding to a certain month into a temp table from an SQL database.

```
DROP TABLE
    #ComPAIR_Alliance_Table
SELECT
    IMOno
    ,period
    ,[service]
    ,alliances
INTO
    #ComPAIR_Alliance_Table
FROM
    com_COMPAIR.dbo.Data_BlueWaterCapacity_US_2
WHERE
    LEFT(period, 7) = '2015-03'

SELECT
     *
FROM #ComPAIR_Alliance_Table
```

The period field is in the following format: `2015-03-29 00:00:00.000`

However, my code just returns an empty temp table with the right column names but no rows (even though I know for sure rows with that date exist in my table). I have already made sure that the period column is indeed a string by using is.numeric.

Could someone please help me out with what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the datatype of `period`? I bet it's a `date`.

Comment: Is period a string column? or a date/time column? Note that your query is non-SARGable.

Comment: I also tried using YEAR(period) = 2019 AND MONTH(period) = 09 but this did not work either

Comment: You don;t check the datatype using ISNUMERIC. You look at table structure or like `SELECT sql_variant_property(period, 'basetype')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing `Period` is a `date`. If it is, stop treating it like a `varchar`, it isn't one. If you want values from March 2015 then do:

```
WHERE period >= '20150301'
  AND period < '20150401'
```

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? It's the same solution as Salman.A's, which were both posted at the same time. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a date/datetime/datetime2 then you can compare it with `2015-03` like:

```
WHERE period >= '2015-03-01'
AND   preiod <  DATEADD(MONTH, 1, '2015-03-01')
```

In case there is confusion:

- The above will match all March 2015 dates such as `2015-03-31`, `2015-03-31 23:59:59` and `2015-03-31 23:59:59.9999999`
- The above is sargable: the `DATEADD` part does not depend on the table rows

Comment: And now this has 2 down votes? I'd really like to hear why. If someone does have something to add here, please do share. :)

Answer (score 0):

LEFT is doing some weird stuff, because **LEFT causes an implicit cast to String from Date**.  You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438276/why-does-using-left-on-getdate-change-it-to-a-different-data-type) for more information, but you're getting exactly what you told SQL to get - a join on rows where the left 7 characters of period equal '2015-03' which will not happen, since you're liking comparing against something like 'Jan 01'

Answer (score 0):

The `LEFT` function needs to implicitly convert your `datetime` column to a `varchar` value to do it's work. SQL Server is choosing the `varchar` format of the date based on it's internationalization settings. On my server, its `Mar 29 2015 12:00AM`, and `LEFT` yields `Mar 29`. That's why it's not equal to `2015-03`.

You should treat your column as a datetime and then perform the comparison using a valid datetime comparison, like this :

`WHERE period BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '1/31/2015'`

Comment: While your answer can lead to right result, it still a locale dependent and relies on language settings. Such format is a safer alternative: `WHERE period BETWEEN '20150101' AND '20150131'`

Answer (score -2):

the date is stored as a date type. You may want to try

```
where convert(varchar(20), period,121)
```

which would convert it to string...

Comment: And prevent any use of an index? That's a pretty bad idea.