# WHERE clause changes CAST result in SELECT statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `[dbo].[temp_toerase]` with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_toerase]
(
    [NeedByDate] [date] NULL,
    [insertdate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I added a few rows to this table.

When I run the following query, I get the correct result with the `CAST` function:

```
SELECT
    NeedByDate, 
    CAST(NeedByDate AS varchar(10)) 
FROM
    temp_toerase
```

[image]

If I run it with the `WHERE` clause, the `CAST` returns a different value:

```
SELECT
    NeedByDate, 
    CAST(NeedByDate AS varchar(10)) 
FROM
    temp_toerase 
WHERE
    insertdate <> '3/9/2021 2:54:08 PM'
```

[image]

Why does the `WHERE` clause change how the `CAST` works?

I'm doing this because the ASP.NET gridview is displaying the time part even though the column (in T-SQL) is of type `DATE`.

Comment: You've got your columns mixed up... your queries show `cast(NeedByDate...` but your results show `cast(InsertDate....`. Because they are different datatypes they have a different default format. Really you should do your formatting in your front end, the gridview allows you to format your datetime and remove the time. Otherwise you should look at using `convert()` because you can specify the format required.

Comment: What do you mean? Why would the CAST in the select statement result change based on the where clause?

Comment: It doesn't - one set of results is showing `cast(NeedByDate as varchar(10))` and the other is showing `cast(InsertDate as varchar(10))`, and one is a `date` column and the other is a `datetime` column, and cast formats those 2 datatypes differently.

Comment: Try this `select NeedByDate, cast(NeedByDate as varchar(10)), InsertDate, cast(InsertDate as varchar(10)) from temp_toerase`

Comment: I'm not showing InsertDate in either set. I only use InsertDate in the WHERE clause.

Comment: I'm suggesting you've made a mistake, because that doesn't happen when I try it, only when I change column.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5fa92a029034a9c60e6a355fc3e55994

Comment: I can't reproduce it either, yet here it is.

Comment: I suggest something is not as it seems somewhere. But regardless, use `convert()` and specify the format. `cast` is not intended for use in formatting.

Comment: The same thing occur with convert(). But I'll close question and reopen with more detail. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It won't occur with convert if you set the style...

Comment: possibly this https://stackoverflow.com/q/3636315/73226

Comment: ASP.net receives the `date` value from SQL Server, and has no option other than to put it into C# `datetime`, you need to set the formatting on the C# side

Comment: I can reproduce this on a database set to 2008 compatibility mode. It is the same issue with inconsistent default styles used when the query is auto parameterised vs when it isn't (the first one has nothing to parameterise)